# Vue.js on local, NGINX docker container, how to save files with Node?

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, vue.js

I apologize if this is a general question, but apparently what I'm googling doesn't make sense, and I don't have anyone at my work I can ask.

Here's my situation:

- Simple Vue.js app created with the Vue CLI 3.5, with an `<input type="file">`. Nothing hooked up yet when the form submits.
- Docker container with Node and NGINX that pulls in and builds my Vue app - this is working. I basically copied the Dockerfile right from [the vue.js site](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/dockerize-vuejs-app.html#Real-World-Example).
- Now I need to store the file from the web app (and eventually FTP it to another server).

It was suggested I use Node, but I'm new to all the server-side stuff, so I don't know *how* to do that. My container has both Node and NGINX in it running the app, so can I stick with one container? And how do I build locally for development and then transfer that to the Docker image?

I'm just looking for pointers/articles/tutorials to help me think about this the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Attention opinion:

In my experience NGINX is more of a router managing traffic.

Its in the name of Node to make a single one per task. So () i think its uesfull to split those.

Node is similar to "frotnend" except you have access to common system apis - wrapped by node.

But basically like you consume rest or graphql apis you can do with node.

Best is to simply peek into the basics you most likely gonna need:

file system, stream,...

https://nodejs.org/api/